# Does it true that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sin\left(\frac{1}{u_{n}}\right)}{\frac{1}{u_{n}}}=1$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

We know that $$\lim_{x→0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$$

Let $(u_{n})_{n≥1}$ be any positive increasing sequence satisfying $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}u_{n}=+∞$

Can we deduce that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sin\left(\frac{1}{u_{n}}\right)}{\frac{1}{u_{n}}}=1$$

I thought that since $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}u_{n}=+∞$, then I can use the variable change $m=u_{n}$ and then $x=1/m$ but I am not sure about this fact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is true by the sequential definition of a limit. Since you know $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}=1$, we know it is true that for any sequence $a_n$ in $ \mathbb{R}-\{0\}$ that goes to $0$, we have that $\frac{\sin(a_n)}{a_n}\rightarrow 1$ as $n\rightarrow \infty.$

Also, I don't see a need for you sequence to be non-negative, so you may loosen that restriction.